# I'm having trouble with my program! New to C and can't figure this out

Tags: c

Let me start by saying I know this is not the most efficient way of writing this program, but this is the way I've done it, sloppy or not, I just need help understanding why I cannot grab values from my array.

If you run this monstrosity, it will spit out 0s for i and t, my temporary variables. I'm not done setting up all the bug stops, but that is not a my issue. I'm just confused and lost as to why I cannot grab values from my arrays and assign them to new variables. Any input would be GREATLY appreciated. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int day1, day2, mnth1, mnth2;
    int x, y, i, t;
    int jan[31] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};
    int feb[28] = {32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59};
    int mar[31] = {60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90};
    int apr[30] = {91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120};
    int may[31] = {121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151};
    int jun[30] = {152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181};
    int jul[31] = {182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212};
    int aug[31] = {213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243};
    int sep[30] = {244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273};
    int oct[31] = {274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304};
    int nov[30] = {305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334};
    int dec[31] = {335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364,365};

    printf("Please enter the information that is asked only\n");
    printf("Please enter the first date: ");
    scanf("%d", &mnth1);
    scanf("%d", &day1);

    printf("%d", mnth1);
    printf(" ");
    printf("%d\n", day1);

    if (mnth1 < 1 | day1 < 1) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (mnth1 == 1) {
        if (day1 = jan[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 2) {
        if (day1 = feb[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 28) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 3) {
        if (day1 = mar[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 4) {
        if (day1 = apr[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 30) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 5) {
        if (day1 = may[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 6) {
        if (day1 = jun[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 30) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 7) {
        if (day1 = jul[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 8) {
        if (day1 = aug[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 9) {
        if (day1 = sep[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 30) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 10) {
        if (day1 = oct[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 11) {
        if (day1 = nov[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 30) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 == 12) {
        if (day1 = dec[i]) {
            x = i + 1;
        } else if (day1 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth1 > 12) {
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Please enter the second date: ");
    scanf("%d", &mnth2);
    scanf("%d", &day2);

    printf("%d", mnth2);
    printf(" ");
    printf("%d\n", day2);

    if (mnth2 == 1) {
        if (day2 = jan[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 2) {
        if (day2 = feb[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 28) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 3) {
        if (day2 = mar[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 4) {
        if (day2 = apr[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 30) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 5) {
        if (day2 = may[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 6) {
        if (day2 = jun[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 30) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 7) {
        if (day2 = jul[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 8) {
        if (day2 = aug[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 9) {
        if (day2 = sep[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 30) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 10) {
        if (day2 = oct[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 11) {
        if (day2 = nov[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 30) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 == 12) {
        if (day2 = dec[t]) {
            y = t + 1;
        } else if (day2 > 31) {
            return 0;
        }
    } else if (mnth2 > 12) {
        return 0;
    }

    printf("The difference between these two dates is:\n");
    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%d\n", y);
    //  printf("%d\n", y - x);
}
```

Comment: Hey @Ted, welcome to Stackoverflow. We are pretty choosy on questions around here, but we love (and are) noobs. I'd suggest your question will have better success if you could write a simpler program that demonstrates the specific problem. I suspect otherwise your question may be put on hold until improvements are made.

Comment: Some things that I noticed while looking over your code.  `|` is not the same thing as `||` and `=` is not the same thing as `==`.

Comment: Read about `switch` statement (for `mnth1` variable): it will make your program smaller end easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

First, many of your secondary `if` statements are using the assignment operator `=` and not the comparison `==`.

Second, where is `i` supposed to be set initially?  If your goal is for `x` to be the value from the array, just set it: `x = dec[day1]`